# Multiple actions to one JButton

Tags: java, jbutton

How do I add multiple actions to one button when using Java?

For example, if I have something like this:

```
JButton button1 = new JButton("Button");
button1.addActionListener(this);
button1.setActionCommand("buttonPressed");
```

Can I just add a new `setActionCommand`, or do I have to do something else?

Comment: You’re writing Java code, not JavaScript. Please learn the difference.

Comment: You can try it yourself very easy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend calling the methods you want to run from the method you set in `setActionCommand(...)`.

```
button1.setActionCommand(foo);

...

void foo() {
    bar();
}
```